# Map dates into intervals with oracle sql

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, mapping

I have the following problem:

I have a start field (type: timestamp) and an end field (type: timestamp).  Now I want to assign this interval to an hour orientate interval [0-1],[1-0]…...

**Example**:
Start: 14:20
End: 16:45
Result should be something like:
[0-1],[1-2]…..[13-14],[14-15],[15-16],[16-17],[17-18]….
   0      0             0          1          1          1          0

**What I have done until now**:
What I have done until now is to map this start-end interval in a bitmask.  This is in a short and efficient way possible. So this bitmask for the example from above looks like (least significant bit corresponds to the range of [0-1]):
( 000000011100000000000000 )2 ≙  114688
Then I make a Bitand to decide if this corresponds to a range:

```
CASE 
                 WHEN Bitand(mask, Power(2, 0)) > 0 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
   END AS g0001, --[0-1]
CASE 
                 WHEN Bitand(mask, Power(2, 1)) > 0 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
   END AS g0102, --[1-2]
…
CASE 
                 WHEN Bitand(mask, Power(2, 23)) > 0 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
 END AS g2324 --[23-24]
```

But this solution is very long, unhandy and repeats much similar lines in the bitand section. Knows anybody shorter/better solution?
PS: No stored Procedures are allowed!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use direct comparisons?

```
(case when extract(hour from start) <= 0 and extract(hour from end) >= 0 then 1 else 0 end) as hour_01,
(case when extract(hour from start) <= 1 and extract(hour from end) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end) as hour_02,
. . .
```

This is about the same amount of code, but it is a bit clearer what you are doing.

Comment: Yes this is definitely clearer. But if there is an alternative which is  shorter (I have forgotten to mention, that this is a subselect. The select  build the sum of each row (24 lines of code more!))  would be very useful. 
Anyway  this suggestion increases the quality my code. => Thank you ;-)